# Sort Pandas Dataframe which contains german umlauts [Solution]

Tags: python, pandas, sorting

I have a pandas dataframe with several series and I sort this dataframe by some of them:

```
df = df.sort_values(by=['Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3', 'Col4', 'Col5'])
```

This works fine! But german umlauts are not in the "german order", so Ä is not between A and B, but instead is sorted after Z. Also "denmark" ist sorted after "Zimmermann", because the pandas sorting algorithm seems to be case-sensetive.

I found solutions for sorting a dataframe by one Series ([e. g. here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57361637/sorting-pandas-dataframe-with-german-umlaute)) but no solution for sorting by several series. In all series, umlauts are possible. So I tried a bit - maybe this helps someone. :-)

---

**Solution:**

```
df = df.sort_values(by=['Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3', 'Col4', 'Col5'], key=lambda col: col.str.lower().str.normalize('NFD'))
```

`str.lower()` solves the problem, that a string "denmark" ist sorted after "Zimmermann"

`str.normalize('NFD')` solves the problem with the german umlauts.

Comment: This works, but if there are mixed numbers (as string) and words, it sorts the numbers incorrectly. For example, it sorts 100 before 20.

How can this be fixed?

Comment: Could you please post your 'solution' as an answer, and accept the answer?  So people know it has been solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution as an answer, so I can accept it as solved:

```
df = df.sort_values(by=['Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3', 'Col4', 'Col5'], key=lambda col: col.str.lower().str.normalize('NFD'))
```

`str.lower()` solves the problem, that a string "denmark" ist sorted after "Zimmermann"

`str.normalize('NFD')` solves the problem with the german umlauts.